can not delete emacs tmp file
I have created a file by emacs29.3 in ubuntu (running in virtualbox). That folder is a share folder from windows11. Today I deleted the ubutun22.04 and installed a new ubuntu24.04 and add the same share folder.
But when I try to open the file with emacs29.3 again, it says file locked by user (previous user in old ubuntu).
Then I check the file dot files and found one with that file name. I think I need delete it to remove the locked message. but when I run the delete command, it failed:
sudo rm .#a.org 
rm: cannot remove '.#a.org': Operation not permitted


sudo still can not delete it.

Is this really an Emacs question?
